# How to get location x minutes into a route (Google Maps API)?

Tags: google-maps, directions

Given an origin and destination, I want to get the location x minutes into that route; is this possible through the Google Maps API?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no.

The closest you could easily get is that you know what legs would have been completed in the required time, and how much of the current leg remains.

Calculating the location of the point that much time into that leg would be more tricky.